# Terraform error : unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have appied and destroyed my Terraform a couple of times now.
But all of a sudden it drops this error message

```
Error: json: error calling MarshalJSON for type googleapi.RawMessage: unexpected end of JSON input
```

This is the resource its referring to:

```
resource "google_dataflow_job" "dataflow_job" {
    project                     = var.project_name
    region                      = var.project_region
    name                        = "${var.app_name}-${random_id.rng.hex}"
    template_gcs_path           = "gs://dataflow-templates/latest/PubSub_Subscription_to_BigQuery"
    temp_gcs_location           = "gs://capstonev4-bucket"
    skip_wait_on_job_termination = false
    on_delete                   = "cancel"

    parameters = {
        inputSubscription = "projects/cloud-consulting-sandbox/subscriptions/capstonev3-stream-subscription"
        outputTableSpec = "cloud-consulting-sandbox.capstonev4_dataset.capstonev4_table"
    }
}
```

There are no JSON elements involved. Can someone give any pointers to how it compiles and where i can check this?

I have tried to alter the variables from strings to variables that point to other resources but it generates the same error.

Comment: It seems like you've encountered this bug: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/7449

Comment: @MartinAtkins Yes it seems like it. Ill just place the Dataflow job outside Terraform for now. Thanks for looking into this.